# How to know if a file descriptor is opened?

Tags: c, unix

Here I have some questions when using open in a multi-thread case with [`pthread_cancel()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cancel.html). In the thread I need to open some files to read.

So my first question is that do I need to enclose the fields where I use those opened file descriptors with [`pthread_cleanup_push()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cleanup_push.html) and [`pthread_cleanup_pop()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cleanup_pop.html). I think if the thread is cancelled with the files still opened, it won't be good.

However, as far as I know, the [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) function itself is a possible cancellation point. And I don't know if the file descriptor is opened or not if a cancel happened there (or where can I get the information of that?)

At last, is there a Unix interface to tell if the file descriptor is opened or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, using `pthread_cleanup_push()` is a good idea.
2. If the thread is cancelled in `open()`, the file descriptor won't be open so the cleanup code simply has to close anything that was opened previously.
3. You can use [`fstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html) to check if a file descriptor is open. Or you can use one of the other functions that take a file descriptor as an argument, looking for `EBADF` (bad file descriptor) if the descriptor is not open).  The advantage of `fstat()` is that it is a pure interrogation function whereas most others try to change something about the descriptor.  [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) can do queries too.

Comment: Are you *sure* the file descriptor is guaranteed not to be open if a cancellation happens in `open`?  The only language I see in POSIX that might make such a guarantee is "The side-effects of acting upon a cancellation request while suspended during a call of a function are the same as the side-effects that may be seen in a single-threaded program when a call to a function is interrupted by a signal and the given function returns [EINTR]" and I wouldn't trust `open` not to have opened the file if it failed with `EINTR` (*regardless* of what the standard says on that point).

Comment: The file descriptor is not open as far as the application is concerned until the `open()` call returns successfully, meaning it wasn't a cancellation point.  The application has no way to know what file descriptor was going to be returned (well, it there's the sequential allocation, lowest not currently open file descriptor property, but that's hard to determine in a multi-threaded application).  So, it must be up to the kernel to keep track of things until the `open()` returns successfully.

Comment: The specific scenario I'm imagining (and yes, this would be a QoI bug in the C library if not an outright conformance violation, but it is the sort of bug I can easily imagine existing) is that the check for cancellation happens immediately after the system call returns to user space -- within one or two instructions, before the libc stub returns.  So, as far as the kernel is concerned, the system call succeeded and the file is open, but the application does not get a chance to do anything with it before the thread is cancelled.

Comment: I think cancellation is a kernel-space operation, not a user-space operation (but I stand to be corrected if someone's scrutinized the code).  And yes, it becomes a QoI issue.  The `open()` page says nothing about cancellation; it is a cancellation point, but it doesn't need to say anything.  _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ The section on thread cancellation does say: _The side-effects of acting upon a cancellation request while suspended during a call of a function are the same as the side-effects that may be seen in a single-threaded program when a call to a function is interrupted by a signal and the given function returns [EINTR]. Any such side-effects occur before any cancellation cleanup handlers are called._  If `open()` returns with `-1` because of `EINTR`, then there is no open file descriptor from that call to `open()`.  Ditto, therefore, for thread cancellation.

Comment: I'd have to go dig through the code myself to say much more specifically, but I know that at least some pthreads implementations implement cancellation with signals, and that at least some Unix kernels always check for pending signals in the syscall exit path (so, technically before returning to user space; but from user space's perspective, the signal is delivered after the return to user space, but before *any* further instructions execute).  If such an implementation did not take special care with cancellation on `open`, it would "naturally" happen with the file already open.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if a thread can be cancelled while it holds the only reference to open file descriptors, you need to use `pthread_cleanup_push`/`pop` to ensure they are closed; otherwise they will leak.

Indeed, the `open` function itself is a cancellation point, as are several other resource allocation functions (here is [a complete list of cancellation points](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_05_02)).  There is language in the standard that can be read to require the file *not* to have been opened yet if a cancel happens at an `open`, but I do not trust implementations to have gotten that right.  The only 100% reliable way to deal with this problem is to use `pthread_setcancelstate` to disable cancellation while opening files (or allocating other resources), and reenable it only after the subsequent `pthread_cleanup_push`.

You can tell whether a file descriptor is open by seeing whether a no-op `fcntl` fails with errno set to `EBADF`, but DO NOT DO THIS.  It is intrinsically racey -- in between the check and the code control-dependent on the check, another thread may reuse that file descriptor number and your program will misbehave, possibly catastrophically (e.g. overwriting the wrong file).

Comment: Are you sure about the crash? The kernel should be keeping threads from stepping too violently on each other's toes and causing crashes. If one thread reads while another closes, one of them will fail with an error; it shouldn't be a crash. If another thread opens a file descriptor between the time your code checks that it is closed and is told it is closed and the time when you act on that ... it depends on what you're doing. If you `dup2()` to the descriptor that was closed, it will mean that the other thread isn't writing to the file it thought it was, but ... that shouldn't be a crash.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, 'crash' is maybe too strong a word -- I was thinking of the 'other thread isn't writing to the file it thought it was' scenario.  On the other hand, overwriting the wrong file is often *worse* than crashing.

Comment: Agreed that confusion over what file descriptor is working with what file is bad, but I guess it depends on what they're all up to.  I think the advice would have to be 'be careful with `dup2()` and its `fcntl()` counterpart.  Most other file descriptor generation calls (`open()`, `socket()`, `opendir()`, `creat()` if you ever use it, etc) generate the file descriptor and make sure the new one is unique within the process. There is of course the 'file descriptor N got closed in thread 1 and reallocated by an open in thread 2' problem. But processes should know which file descriptors are open.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think the OP is imagining 'in my cleanup handler I will detect whether fd N is open, and if it is, I will close it', and I think that is quite likely to hit the 'fd N got closed in thread 1 and reallocated by thread 2' scenario, and that could easily lead to on-disk data corruption (e.g. if thread 2 is not done writing out a file when thread 1 closes it).

Comment: If that's what the OP is thinking, then he should think again.  There's also a note about: _Use of asynchronous cancelability while holding resources which potentially need to be released may result in resource loss. Similarly, cancellation scopes may only be safely manipulated (pushed and popped) when the thread is in the deferred or disabled cancelability states._  It requires care to get this right.  The data structures recording what's in use must be managed in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: Between two answers and a series of mini-essays in the comments, the OP has most of the information he'll need.  The general information on [POSIX Threads](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09) should be read, too.  That's where my two big quotes come from.